# Set LinearLayout collapse direction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontalScrollView with a LinearLayout in it, that has views in it. 
It looks something like:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
|  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |   E  |   F  |  G   |  H   |   I  |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The linear layout is wider than the screen, so only some of the items are visible. Let's assume that items C through F are visible.

On some cases I remove many view at once, but at least one of the visible views is not removed. 
In our case, lets say that view E is going to remain, while other visible items (C,D,F) are going to be removed from layout.

What happens is, all remained views are collapsing to the left to fill the gaps, sometimes causing view E to move to the left and disappear from the visible area.
What I want is to make the linear layout shrink around the chosen view (E)

Is there a way to cause items in linear layout to close the gap relative to a certain view or x coordinate? (in my case, relative to view E)
This way, items G-I will go to the left, while items A and B will collapse to the right.

I've tried to set different parameters, such as gravity and pivot, but no luck. any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

adding the LayoutTransitioner I am using:

```
    mTabStripTransitioner = new LayoutTransition();

    AnticipateOvershootInterpolator ao = new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator();
    AnticipateOvershootInterpolator softAo = new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1f);
    ObjectAnimator animOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "translationY", 0, 300);
    ObjectAnimator animIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "translationY", 300, 0);

    animIn.addListener(animationListenerIn);
    animOut.addListener(animationListenerOut);

    animOut.setInterpolator(ao);
    animIn.setInterpolator(softAo);


    mTabStripTransitioner.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, animIn);
    mTabStripTransitioner.setDuration(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, MEDIUM_ANIM);
    mTabStripTransitioner.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, animOut);
    mTabStripTransitioner.setDuration(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, LONG_ANIM);
    mTabStripTransitioner.setStagger(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 50);
    mTabStripTransitioner.setStagger(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING, 50);

    tabStrip.setLayoutTransition(mTabStripTransitioner);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "issue" you're facing is due the fact that the `HorizontalScrollView` is trying to keep the same scroll position. And when you're making some views `GONE` that are "earlier" in the hierarchy (to the left of the current position) , the scroll position will remain the same but it will no longer point to the same position in the content.

What you can do is:

When you're removing (or setting the `visibility` to `GONE`) a `View` to the left of the current position, you need to [manually scroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int)) your `HorizontalScrollView` **BY** the `width` of the removed `View`.

Comment: issue is, I animate the transition with layout transitioner.

This means that in this solution I need to scroll together with the animation on every animation step, making it almost impossible to supply smooth experience

Comment: how exactly are you performing this animation? maybe it's not really "almost impossible", maybe it's quite doable...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you basically need to set the LinearLayout `weight`. This will ensure that the remaining space is filled according to the weight value.
See here for the [android dev example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

The other value you need is the visiblity modifier `INVISIBLE` and `GONE`. 
So instead of removing the Layouts you can set them to `INVISBILE` to take the current space in account or `GONE` to free up the space.
[See here for the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can achieve it by using `HorizontalRecyclerView`.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you changed(either added or deleted) the list values.

Comment: Won't it have the same effect as the OP is having currently?

Comment: I made a short test with RecyclerView (vertical for the ease of things, but it's not important)
Question is, is there a way to set the collapse direction with that RecyclerView